# Histogram Time Slider in Legacy Style ESRI JavaScript API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I tried to modify the sample code [Histogram Time Slider ArcGIS API](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/widget_histogram_time_slider.html) for JavaScript  from AMD to Legacy style. However,
I found the histogram was not shown in the bottom in the application (link listed below). I am wondering if you could provide valuable opinions on the application. I am not sure if the Histogram Time slider not supported in DoJo <1.8

The Histogram time slider application based on Legacy style
http://maps.nmt.edu/JSTest/Histogram/Histogram_Legacy.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two corrections needed here

1. The legacy event name is **onUpdateEnd**, not update-end
2. When initializing the Histogram Slide, pass it **sliderElem**, not dojo.byId("bottom-div")

You should be good then!

More explanation on the 2nd step:
The bottom-div element is already registered with Dojo. It is a Dojo ContentPane so it can't be used for another Dojo Widget. So we have to construct an element inside bottom-div. Otherwise you will see an error in console like this

```
Tried to register widget with id==bottom-div but that id is already registered(…)
```

I saw in your code that you have already constructed the element in the variable sliderElem. And also saw it being used in the Esri sample.

http://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=widget_histogram_time_slider

Comment: Thank you for the valuable opinions. I am new in JavaScript. I have followed your instructions. First, I have changed the event name from update-end to **onUpdateEnd**. However, could you provide more information on the point 2, in the source code, line 82 and 97, I can see dojo.byId("bottom-div"). Could you provide more detailed information on these two lines? Many thanks,
Hank

Comment: I just tried to replace the dojo.byId("bottom-div") in the line 97. Wow! And then I can see the Histogram. I appreciate your opinions. If possible, could you share how you tell the error in the line 97 and provide the suggestion "pass it sliderElem, not dojo.byId("bottom-div")" Many thanks,<br>
Hank

Comment: updated my answer with explanation